# Error to parse date: "Unparseable date: "Jue 28-05-2016 22:30" (at offset 0)"

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, unparseable

i'm new in Android and I want to parse a string with a date to convert it to a calendar object and then send it to the Android Calendar. My string value is *Jue 28-05-2015 22:30* (Jue for Jueves, thursday in spanish) and my code looks like this:

```
    fechaevento = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime ="Jue 28-05-2016 22:30" 
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm");

    btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                fechaevento.setTime(sdf.parse(beginTime));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, fechaevento.getTimeInMillis())
                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, nameEvento.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, descriptionEvento.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("FECHA_M", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

When I try to run it i get the error:  Unparseable date: "Jue 28-05-2016 22:30" (at offset 0)

Comment: This seems like a locale issue to me. Also are you sure about "kk" in your format?

Comment: @RC.: the `kk` pattern represents hour of day in the 24-hour clock. If you use `hh`, then you get a 12-hour clock and you need an AM/PM field somewhere in the pattern. (TIL: the Javadocs specify that `kk` pattern as a value in the range [1-24], where [0-23] would make infinitely more sense to people in a locale that uses 24-hour notation. Java's date/time support could use one more incorrect edge case I suppose)

Comment: I know what "kk" means, it's just the first time I see it, so it's strange; Here we use `00:10` for ten past midnight (and we use 24-h clock)

Comment: @RC. Sorry, I didn't realize from your comment that you knew. I didn't mean to be condescending.

Comment: @Barend no worries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the Spanish Locale to your date formatter:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm", new Locale("es"));
```