# Unparseable date: "Thu, 13 Oct 2016 21:06:31 +0200" (at offset 8)

Tags: java, android, date, parsing, locale

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911900/2114590) code to parse a Date, but in this case my date String is as follows:

> Fri, 14 Oct 2016 13:56:15 +0200

(spanish Spain)

Don't know offset 8 and, or how to fix that parse error.

PD: I've tried too [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885993/2114590) solution with no success.

My code....

public String convertDate(String d) {

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", new Locale("es"));
try
{

    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(d);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    //System.out.println("date : "+simpleDateFormat.format(date));
}
catch (ParseException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
}
return "Error en la fecha";
```

}

Logat

```
I/System.out: Exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 14 Oct 2016 13:56:15 +0200" (at offset 0)
I/System.out: Exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 13 Oct 2016 11:48:48 +0200" (at offset 0)
I/System.out: Exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 12 Oct 2016 13:57:02 +0200" (at offset 0)
I/System.out: Exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 13 Oct 2016 21:06:31 +0200" (at offset 0)
```

PD2: Using Android Studio

Comment: Please show your code here as a [mcve]

Comment: Fri and Oct are English.

Comment: Not sure, but offset 8 might refer to (0-based) position 8 in the string, that is, the capital letter O in Oct. Seems to confirm that @ElliottFrisch is on the right track.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm showing the code...TWICE, linking both examples in the main post,...

Comment: @Mark Your own code should be shown here, not a link, and not someone else's code

Comment: @Mark Your title says offset 8 but your example error codes say offset 0. Please take care when drafting your Question. Use the "edit" link or button to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Locale`

Specify `Locale` to **match the human language of your input string**. In this case, English rather than Spanish, `Locale.English`.

If omitted, your JVM’s current default locale is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit. **Always specify your desired/expected locale.** Making the locale argument optional is a flaw in the API design in my opinion.

## RFC 1123 & 822

Your input string happens to comply with the standard formats of RFC 1123 and RFC 822.

This format is predefined by `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` constant. So no need to define a formatting pattern.

## `ZonedDateTime`

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Parse your input string as a `ZonedDateTime` using the predefined formatting pattern.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "Fri, 14 Oct 2016 13:56:15 +0200" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME 
);
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain I'm using Android Studio, so there is no ZonedDateTime

Comment: @Mark Add the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library to your project, an Android adaptation of the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7. Well worth the bother as the legacy date-time classes are an awful mess.